# Add/Remove data members with template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, enable-if

Consider the following code :

```
template<bool AddMembers> class MyClass
{
    public:
        void myFunction();
        template<class = typename std::enable_if<AddMembers>::type> void addedFunction();

    protected:
        double myVariable;
        /* SOMETHING */ addedVariable;
};
```

In this code, the template parameter `AddMembers` allow to add a function to the class when it's `true`. To do that, we use an `std::enable_if`.

My question is : is the same possible (maybe with a trick) for data members variable ? (in a such way that `MyClass<false>` will have 1 data member (`myVariable`) and `MyClass<true>` will have 2 data members (`myVariable` and `addedVariable`) ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A conditional base class may be used:

```
struct BaseWithVariable    { int addedVariable; };
struct BaseWithoutVariable { };

template <bool AddMembers> class MyClass
    : std::conditional<AddMembers, BaseWithVariable, BaseWithoutVariable>::type
{
    // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 34):

First off, your code just won't compile for `MyClass<false>`. The `enable_if` trait is useful for *deduced* arguments, not for class template arguments.

Second, here's how you could control members:

```
template <bool> struct Members { };

template <> struct Members<true> { int x; };

template <bool B> struct Foo : Members<B>
{
    double y;
};
```

Comment: +++++1 perfect! Mixin with conditional template parameter

Comment: I found this better than the accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: One simple way to remember the point "The enable_if trait is useful for deduced arguments, not for class template arguments." is "SFINAE can be used on a member function of a class template which is also a function template but not on a member function of a class template which is not." `template <bool AddMem = AddMembers> typename std::enable_if<AddMem>::type addedFunction();` will remove the compile time error when `AddMembers = false`.