# define implicit conversion from template class to primitive type based on other template

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion

I have a class defined by two templates.

```
template<typename A, typename B> my_class {
private:
    A value;

public:
    operator A () {
        return this->value;
    }
};
```

I want to define an implicit conversion between the class and the first type in the template, but only for a specific second type on the template. Since `A` is a C++ primitive type I can't define the conversion on that side. I tried `std::enable_if` like this

```
operator typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<B, specific_B_type>::value, NumT>::type () {
    return this->value;
}
```

but I get the compile error

```
Error   C2833   'operator type' is not a recognized operator or type    dimensional_analysis
```

Is there any way to do this without having to define the entire class specialized for `B = specific_B_type`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just discovered that my answer doesn't actually work... It seems that this disables the whole class instantiation, not just the operator... Could you unaccept it, so I can delete it? :)

Comment: Okay, found another (much simpler) solution. Is that still what you want?

Comment: I'm currently using the first solution you gave `template<typename Constraint = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<B, specific_B_type>::value, void>::type>`. It seems to work but I may not have tested it thoroughly enough. What is your best solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried creating an instance of the class, where `B != specific_B_type`? I seems that selectively disabling member functions based on class template parameters doesn't work, as it is not possible to have a class with a ill-defined member function even if that function is never used.

Comment: What the best solution is depends on your use case. If all you want is to get a compile time error if you try to use the implicit conversion and `B != specific_B_type`, then you should go with my new solution. It is simple and allows you to specifiy a custom error message. If you want something more complicated, like allowing implicit conversion for some `B` and explicit conversion otherwise, you can check out the solutions in the link I posted. All of them are, however, somewhat more involved.

Comment: Ok, I tested my code a bit more and discovered that your first solution worked well when compiled with Visual C++ 14.0 but failed with GCC 7.2.0. Since I want both to work I'm going to use the inheritance described in the question you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117912/add-remove-data-members-with-template-parameters). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907372/conditionally-compile-a-conversion-operator-based-on-numeric-template-parameter#46907524) question which just came out. It seems you can salvage my first solution by copying the class template paramter into a dummy function template parameter. You learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `static_assert` to check if the conversion should be allowed:

```
operator A() 
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<B, specific_B_type>::value, "No conversion possible");    
    return this->value;
}
```

However, that means you cannot have an explicit conversion to `A` if `B` is not `specific_B_type`. If you need that, you can have a look at the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117912/add-remove-data-members-with-template-parameters) question about adding and removing members based on template parameters.