# Conditionally compile a conversion operator based on numeric template parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, typecast-operator

I have a `template <bool P> class Foo` with lots of code in it. I want to be able to convert `Foo<true>`'s into `Foo<false>`'s, i.e. have an `operator Foo<false>()` method. But the compiler doesn't like such a method existing for Foo, it only likes it for `Foo<true>`, and gives a warning about how the "operator will not be called for implicit or explicit conversions" (GCC 5.4.x)

It doesn't seem like I can use SFINAE for this: `std::enable_if` works with types; and a value-variant I tried out (where the true case has a `value` rather than a `type` member) didn't help either.

How can I get this operator to only be compiled for `Foo<false>` (other than specializing `Foo<false>` different and duplicating all of my code)?

My best attempt so far has been:

```
template <bool P> class Foo {
    // etc. etc.
    template <bool OtherValue>
    operator Foo<OtherValue>()
    {
        static_assert(OtherValue, "You should not be using this conversion!");
        // conversion code here
        return Foo<false>(args,go,here);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a conversion operator and not a constructor?

Comment: @André - That doesn't solve the issue, really. It only makes sure the compiler will complain over duplicate definitions when `foo<false>` is copied (assuming a copy c'tor is also present).

Comment: @André: I didn't think I could get the ctor to only exist for `Foo<false>`. But - that's an idea, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I get this operator to only be compiled for `Foo<false>` (other than specializing `Foo<false>` different and duplicating all of my code)?

```
template <bool P> 
struct Foo 
{
    template <bool P2 = P, typename = std::enable_if_t<P2 == true>>
    operator Foo<false>()
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

Using `P2 = P` delays the evaluation of the `enable_if_t` to when the conversion operator is actually being used *(instead of class instantiation)*.

---

If we tried to simply write:

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<P == true>>
operator Foo<false>()
{
    return {};
}
```

`std::enable_if_t<P == true>` would be evaluated during `Foo<P>`'s instantiation as there is no substitution occurring when the member functions are instantiated.  The substitution is happening when `Foo` is instantiated - therefore SFINAE cannot take place *(as there isn't any overload resolution set yet)*.

By adding a `bool P2 = P` default parameter, we delay substitution to the instantiation of the conversion operator. This happens during overload resolution, so SFINAE can take place.

This answer explains it better than I can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13401982/598696

Comment: Ah, how sneaky of you! But why is the evaluation delayed? Can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: @einpoklum: added some more explanation and a link.

Answer (score 3):

Your best attempt is actually not far off. You need to turn the conversion operator into a template so that SFINAE could work. Just enforce it only for the case `P` is true:

```
template<bool P>
struct foo {
    template<bool V = P, std::enable_if_t<V>* = nullptr>
    operator foo<false>() {
        return {};
    }
};
```

The operator is a template with all parameters having default arguments. So it can be used. However, since the check is on `V`, we delay the verification of the operator until overload resolution. Then SFINAE eliminates it.

Comment: Isn't it better to @VittorioRomero's trick rather than having pointers pop up?

Comment: @einpoklum - Define "better"? It's the same trick. Vittorio's version relies on failure in the argument, while this one relies on failure in the parameter. In the general case (not this one), a cheeky programmer can supply a type explicitly to get around a check (there's no way to do it with conversion operators however). But if the the parameter fails, an attacker has no recourse. So TL;DR: in this case it doesn't matter, in the general case I prefer to SFINAE on the parameter. I wrote this one by instinct.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an helper struct and specilization to externalize your operator:

```
template <bool P> class Foo; // Forward declaration

template <bool P> struct FooConverterHelper {}; // False case: no conversion operator

template <> struct FooConverterHelper<true>
{
    operator Foo<false>();
};


template <bool P> class Foo : public FooConverterHelper<P>
{
    // Lot of stuff.
};

// Implementation of you conversion operator
FooConverterHelper<true>::operator Foo<false>()
{
    //auto* that = static_cast<Foo<true>*>(this); // If needed

    return Foo<false>{};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5bc63f33adde5ec)

Comment: I like it. Though spreading the definition around so much can be a pain on readability. +1

Comment: That's "cheating"... of course I do whatever I want in another struct - there I don't have any restrictions. I want this conversion operator for silent conversions the users of my library won't notice.

Comment: @StoryTeller: the other way, having `struct Foo<true> : FooCommon<true> {opearator Foo<false>() {/**/}}; struct Foo<false> : FooCommon<false>{};` would avoid that. but it would be "cheating" even more.